# Comparing several dates

Tags: soilgrids

I understood how to use the API and manages to get the data I want in the area where I want it. But this is just one snapshot in time and the area I'm looking at is changing rapidly.

If I do the same query but at different times, will the data change or is it just one snapshot in time that is not refreshed ?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment SoilGrids does not consider temporal trends, even for the more dynamic properties. All the observation data available in the database is used in the models. The dates when samples were collected range from early 1900's to end of 2010's.